# How to change bar positions using matplotlib.pyplot.barh

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm plotting a horizontal barplot using matplotlib.pyplot.barh, and want to move the bar positions. I didn't find any argument that supports this. Anyone had the same problem?

```
ax1.set_title('Number of Accounts', size=12)
ax1.invert_yaxis()
ax1.invert_xaxis()
ax1.barh(c['Customer Group'], c['n_accts'],color='#f4be92')
```

Right now the bar for 1 is in between 0 and 1, and the one for 2 is in between 1 and 2. Is there a way to move the bars to where their corresponding numbers are?

[image]

Comment: I suppose it depends on what `c['Customer Group']` is and how you produced the labels. Both is not shown in the question. See [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a centered alignment. To do so, you can use pass `align='center'` as an argument to your `ax.barh`. So just use

```
ax1.barh(c['Customer Group'], c['n_accts'],color='#f4be92', align='center')
```

It will center the bars on the y axis. See the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.barh.html) here.

Comment: Thank you so much! so the default value for the align argument is 'center', so passing 'center' didn't make a difference, but passing `align='edge' ` worked!